# How to properly return data from a stateful widget called from another stateful widget?

Tags: flutter

I'm calling a datetime picker widget from a stateful widget. I need to be able to use the selected value from the datetime widget in the widget that called it. What is the proper way to go about this?

This is how the widget that calls it looks. Slimmed down of course.

```
        SingleChildScrollView(
          child:Container(
            //WRAPS ENTIRE SHEET
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                    colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.red],
                    begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    end: Alignment.topCenter,
                    stops: [0.1, 1])),
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .40,
            child: ListView( children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Container(
                  child: DatePicker(optionalText: "")
              ),
            ],),
          ),
        )
      ],);
  }
```

This is the widget the I need to return the data

```
 class _DatePickerState extends State<DatePicker> {
  DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();


   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Container(
      child: Row(
       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
       children: <Widget>[
        Container(
         width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .50,
         height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .07,
         child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(33, 0, 5, 0),
          child: RaisedButton(
           color: Colors.white,
           shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
               borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
           child: dateHyphenReplacer(selectedDate),
           onPressed: () => _selectDate(context),
          ),
         ),
        ),
        Padding(
         padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 10, 0, 10),
         child: Icon(
          Icons.calendar_today,
          color: Colors.white,
          size: 30,
         ),
        ),
        Container(
         child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: AutoSizeText(
           'Choose ${widget.optionalText} Date',
           style: TextStyle(
               color: Colors.white,
               fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
               fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
          ),
         ),
        ),
       ],
      ),
     );
   }

   Future<void> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: selectedDate,
        firstDate: DateTime(2015, 8),
        lastDate: DateTime(2101));
    if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate)
     setState(() {
      selectedDate = picked;
     });
    return selectedDate;
   }

  dateHyphenReplacer(date){
     date = formatDate(date, [mm, '/',dd,'/',yy]);
     return Text('$date', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 20));
  }

  }
```

Comment: declare some variable with some placeholder value like "1 Jan, 1970". Then assign the date you picked from DatePicker to this variable. Then setState

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store `DateTime` variable in the parent widget and pass it to the `DatePicker` constructor. When a `DateTime` is selected, set `widget.selectedDateTime`. This approach however will not automatically rebuild the parent widget, thus not updating any visual references to the `DateTime`.